# Remove links using HTML purifirer

Tags: htmlpurifier

we have different type of users on our site. For a particular type of users, we do not want to show URLs(links) posted by them. We want to remove them altogether.

How can I achieve this through HTML purifier config?

Answer (score 0):

The most robust way to do this is to set %URI.Disable to true.

Comment: Yes, this works fine if i have something like - Content with link <a href ="http://www.google.co.in">abcd</a>
This edits it to 'Content with link abcd'
But my requirement is to remove links like 'Content with link http://www.google.co.in' also